# Why is PhantomJS rendering a PDF wider than specified?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, pdf-generation

I'm trying to render a PDF from a HTML page displaying a report, but it extends the page past the size I specified (A4), being wider and longer than expected.

This is running in Node.js using the [phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) NPM package to access phantom.  In the code attached I'm setting the paperSize by the A4 standard, I've also tried setting it using pixels directly, and setting the viewport size.  Setting the paperSize/viewport size doesn't seem to have an effect on the resulting PDF, and changing the width of the HTML page will change the width of the PDF, however the padding is sill present.

PDF Generation code:

```
const instance = await phantom.create();
        const page = await instance.createPage();
         page.paperSize = {
            format: "A4",
            orientation: "portrait",
            margin: "1cm"
        }

        let appToken = sessionManager.getApplicationSessionToken();
        let url = "http://localhost:" + config.hostPort + "/sales/report?accessKey=" + reportID + "&printMode=true";

        page.addCookie({
            name: "token",
            value: appToken,
            domain: "localhost"
        });

        await page.open(url);

        let repFilename = global.reportStoreLoc + "report" + ++lastReportUID + ".pdf";
        await page.render(repFilename);
        instance.kill();
```

Stylesheet:

```css
* {
    font-family: "IBM Plex Sans";
}

.left {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

td {
    padding-right: 5px;
}

html {
    /*https://fineartprinting.la/pixels-per-inch-file-resolution-for-printing/*/
    width: 700px;
    height: 1100px;
}

#contact {
    font-size: 14;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Screenshot of narrow page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVSvi.png

Screenshot of normal page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gphqe.png

As you can see, that padding still hangs around when the page width changes, and stays the same size.  That padding should not be there, the PDF should just cut off.  I think I'm experiencing the same issue with padding on the bottom of the page, but I'm not sure if that's actually a bug or just the PDF being extended to the bottom of where a A4 page would be.

Comment: add `page.settings.dpi = "96";` after the papersize, to check if anything changes or not.

Comment: `page.settings` isn't defined, and defining it doesn't seem to affect anything (tested at 96 and 50)